# How to count minimum on multiple variables in Julia

Tags: julia

I want to plot correct y-axis limits. So, require to count the maximum y and minimum y.

```
y1=[2 3 4]
y2=[7 5 6]
...
m = minimum(y1)
m = minimum(m, minimum(y2))
```

error message

```
ERROR: MethodError: objects of type Int64 are not callable
Maybe you forgot to use an operator such as *, ^, %, / etc. ?
Stacktrace:
 [1] mapreduce_first(f::Int64, op::Function, x::Int64)
   @ Base ./reduce.jl:419
 [2] mapreduce(f::Int64, op::Function, a::Int64)
   @ Base ./reduce.jl:446
 [3] minimum(f::Int64, a::Int64; kw::Base.Pairs{Symbol, Union{}, Tuple{}, NamedTuple{(), Tuple{}}})
   @ Base ./reduce.jl:725
 [4] minimum(f::Int64, a::Int64)
   @ Base ./reduce.jl:725
 [5] top-level scope
   @ REPL[107]:1
```

Previous code is just a simplified code, in my case, it require parse and get from a loop the pseudo code like:

```
x_data, y_data, names, y_min, y_max = [], [], [], 100, 0
for filename in *.csv
    df = parse_csv(filename)  # df is a dataframe
    push!(names, filename)
    d = df.value
    y_min = minimum(y_min, d)
    ....
end
# plot all file by the y_min, y_max
i=1
for d in y_data;
  lineplot(x_data, d, ylims=(y_min,y_max), name=names[i])
  i += 1
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you don't know the difference between the [`min`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/math/#Base.min) function and the [`minimum`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/#Base.minimum) function (or you're unaware of the `min` function):

> `minimum(itr; [init])`
> Returns the smallest element in **a collection**.

So it gets a collection (E.g., `Array`) and returns the minimum of it.

> `min(x, y, ...)`
> Return the minimum of the arguments.

This one gets indefinite arguments and returns the minimum of them! It can't apply min on the `x` if the `x` is a container by itself!

```
julia> min(2, 3)
2

julia> min([2, 3])
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching min(::Vector{Int64})
```

On the other hand, for the `minimum` function:

```
julia> minimum(2, 3)
ERROR: MethodError: objects of type Int64 are not callable

julia> minimum([2, 3])
2
```

So I wanted to explain these to you to understand your code's meaning better.
We have this `minimum(m, minimum(y2))` expression in your code block. This is literally the same as `minimum(2, 5)`. So you're not passing containers to the function, leading to an error! For this, you should choose `min` instead:

```
julia> m = min(m, minimum(y2))
2
```

Or we can wrap `m` and `minimum(y2)` in a **container** and use the `minimum` function to achieve the overall min:

```
julia> m = minimum([m, minimum(y2)])
2
```

If you follow the explanation, you can absolutely understand the following:

```
julia> min(m, minimum(y2)) == minimum([m, minimum(y2)]) == min(m, min(y2...))
true
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are two solutions:

First. This is simple, just take the minimums of the minimums, etc.

```
julia> min(minimum(y1), minimum(y2))
2

julia> max(maximum(y1), maximum(y2))
7
```

Second solution. This iterates over each pair of values from `y1` and `y2`, takes the minimum/maximum of each pair, and then finds the minimum of those again.

```
julia> minimum(minimum, zip(y1, y2))
2

julia> maximum(maximum, zip(y1, y2))
7
```

Here's a third one:

```
julia> min(y1..., y2...)
2

julia> max(y1..., y2...)
7
```

Elegant, but splatting of vectors is often inefficient in terms of performance.

Comment: Because there will be y3 or maybe y4, I need to step by step count the minimum, is it possible?

Comment: `minimum(Iterators.flatten((y1,y2)))` is also nice option.

Comment: You can do `max(maximum(y1), maximum(y2), maximum(y3))`, etc. as far as you like.  If you don't know how many `yn`s there will be, then @DanGetz's solution: `maximum(Iterators.flatten(y))` would be good (if y is a collection of `yn`s).

Comment: Just edit my question, the problem is to keep the maximum value in a variable.  Or, all I can do is just use the "if then else" branch to solve this?